# Unable to reach login page on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, lightdm, unity-greeter

I've recently installed the last version of kubuntu, and, after a few days, the login page has seemingly dissappeared. Instead, when the computer boots I get a black screen in which I can type my password (nothing moves on the screen even when I type) and, when I hit enter, the Plasma DE starts working again.

I've tried changing the default theme just in case that was the broken thing, but it does nothing. However, the screen you get when the device is suspended, asking for your credentials to log back in, works just fine.

I suspect there is a problem with the greeter, but I've found no way to fix it now that it does not use lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm a moron. You see, just before it started not working, I chose to use the Nvidia drivers instead of the default X.org drivers because I was recommended to do so by Kubuntu. I've switched back to X and it fixed! And its also free software, so win win! I think [I can understand Linus Torvals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ) now...